# Convert For Loop to While Loop In Python 3.6

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
for x in a:
    if x[1] in NERTagger:
        kata = ''
        kt = NERTagger[x[1]]
        for y in a:
            if x[0] is not y[0]:
                kata += y[0] + ' '
            elif x[0] == y[0]:
                kata +=  kt + ' '
        hasil.append(kata)
```

How to transform the code above into the while-loop? because there is an if and for-loop again in the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You should post your attempts at this problem so we can help you resolve any errors instead of simply asking for a solution.

Comment: Beware: `x[0] is not y[0]` may not do what you think. `is` tests for object identity, not value equality. Try this: `s='a'; print('ab' is s+'b')`

Comment: This may be a time when `is` is the correct operator (but perhaps not the indexing); note that both `x` and `y` iterate over `a`. But mixing `is` and `==` deserves a comment at least, they are not complementary (in which case `else` would do anyway).

Comment: Could you expand on why you'd want to convert this to `while`? It's almost always better with `for` in Python, and I don't see a clear reason in the code.

Comment: @YannVernier Indeed, the OP may _want_ to do an identity test here (which is why I phrased my comment that way), but that `else` makes me suspect that they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 0

while i < len(a):

  x = a[i]
  i = i + 1
  if x[1] in NERTagger:
    kata = ''
    kt = NERTagger[x[1]]
    j = 0
    while j < len(a):
      y = a[j]
      if x[0] is not y[0]:
          kata += y[0] + ' '
      elif x[0] == y[0]:
          kata +=  kt + ' '
      j = j+1
  hasil.append(kata)
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you added some explanatory text.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in using nested `for` functions.

`while` is just a general form of `for`:

`for` does 3 things:

- defines a variable.
- sets a stopping condition.
- adds 1 to the varaible.

`while` does 1 of these: sets a stop condition.

Comment: Python's `for` is what's known as `foreach` in some languages. It processes every item in an iterable and doesn't care if they are numbers or not. That functionality is part of `range` or `itertools.count`.

Comment: What Yann said. BTW, `for` is not a function.